# python script that conducts a brute force search for four fifth powers that sum to a fifth power

Tags: python

In the following question I am trying to write a python script that conducts a brute force search for four fifth powers that sum to a fifth power. Therefore I am trying to find numbers a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 such that a1^5+a2^5+a3^5+a4^5=a5^5

The range for this search is Nmin=20 and Nmax=200. Also Nmin <= a1 < a2 < a3 < a4 < a5 <= Nmax. So every number must be less then the number before and they have to be in between 20 and 200.

```
import numpy as np

b  = np.arange(20,201)
a = b**5

for x in b:
    for y in b:
        for z in b:
            for w in b:

                lambdas=[x,y,z,w]

                if sum(np.array(lambdas)**5) in a:
                    print((x,y,z,w))
```

Which gives the following output:

```
(20, 64, 128, 192)
(20, 64, 192, 128)
(20, 128, 64, 192)
(20, 128, 128, 128)
(20, 128, 192, 64)
(20, 192, 64, 128)
(20, 192, 128, 64)
```

So this is the wrong output I should be getting the following:

```
(27, 84, 110, 133)
```

It seems that it is not taken in account that a1 < a2 < a3 < a4 < a5. I am looking for some help with fixing this code! Not trying to make it more efficient and run faster just trying to get the correct answer

Comment: @Prune thanks for the edit. Would you be able to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of all, if you want to have that restriction, you need to code it into your loop ranges.  Just use the previous loop's variable as the starting value, and you'll have the desired restriction.

```
import numpy as np

lower = 20
upper = 201
b = np.arange(lower, upper)

a = b**5

for x in b:
    for y in np.arange(x, upper):
        for z in np.arange(y, upper):
            for w in np.arange(z, upper):

                lambdas=[x,y,z,w]
                if sum(np.array(lambdas)**5) in a:

                    print((x,y,z,w))
```

Output:

```
(27, 84, 110, 133)
```

I'm not sure how you ran your previous loop to get the answers you posted.

Why are you bringing in `numpy` for your controls?  That seems to add a layer of software that only slows down your processing.  Instead, just code this as "normal" Python math.  Also, use a `set` for checking your sums, not a list.  Hashing the set will also speed up that one check -- which you make many times.

```
lower = 20
upper = 201
b = range(lower, upper)

a = {i**5 for i in b}

for x in b:
    for y in np.arange(x, upper):
        for z in np.arange(y, upper):
            for w in np.arange(z, upper):
                if x**5 + y**5 + z**5 + w**5 in a:
                    print((x,y,z,w))
```

This got the correct answer and completed within 20 seconds; your original version (once I corrected the indentation) took over 3 minutes.

Comment: this was an intro question to python so we were instructed to us numpy. When I run the first code you have provided I get (20, 64, 128, 192) which is different then what you are getting

Comment: and actually it is listing all the possible answers not factoring in a1 < a2 < a3 < a4 < a5

Comment: @user123, it does, too, restrict the answers to being in ascending order.  Look at the loop limits and the output.  It prints only the one line, rather than all 24 permutations of those integers.

Comment: could you edit this into your first code? I am a little confused

Comment: are you getting the correct answer when you run the first code? the one you have provided

Comment: Yes; each of these produces the correct output, one single line.  If you get something else -- did you do the base-type check that `DSM` suggested?

Comment: nope I will try that out. I will get back to you shortly to see if it worked! In the mean time thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at `a`?  Probably you're seeing something like this:

```
In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([    3200000,     4084101,     5153632,     6436343,     7962624,
           9765625,    11881376,    14348907,    17210368,    20511149,
          24300000,    28629151,    33554432,    39135393,    45435424,
          52521875,    60466176,    69343957,    79235168,    90224199,
         102400000,   115856201,   130691232,   147008443,   164916224,
         184528125,   205962976,   229345007,   254803968,   282475249,
         312500000,   345025251,   380204032,   418195493,   459165024,
         503284375,   550731776,   601692057,   656356768,   714924299,
         777600000,   844596301,   916132832,   992436543,  1073741824,
        1160290625,  1252332576,  1350125107,  1453933568,  1564031349,
        1680700000,  1804229351,  1934917632,  2073071593, -2075960672,
       -1921920421, -1759441920, -1588183139, -1407792928, -1217910897,
       -1018167296,  -808182895,  -587568864,  -355926653,  -112847872,
         142085829,   409302880,   689241911,   982351872,  1289092153,
        1609932704,  1945354155, -1999119360, -1633050899, -1250894368,
        -852125217,  -436207616,    -2594335,   449273376,   919965907,
        1410065408,  1920165909, -1844093856, -1292161145,  -718372864,
        -122086263,   497353888,  1140615419,  1808378880, -1793629635,
       -1074769184,  -329287633,   443547648,  1244482609,  2074276640,
       -1361264605,  -471419904,   449643877,  1402741088, -1906267177,
        -886603776,   167620825,  1257277856, -1911714229,  -748520448,
         452807053,  1693198304, -1321368961,           0,  1363313281,
       -1525405664,   -75216013,  1419936768, -1333877067,   254330464,
        1890661415,  -718766080,  1017084201, -1490604384,   349237147,
       -2052174848,  -103738147,  1900764384,  -332433201,  1787822080,
        -327168815,  1913781536,   -77991229, -2006232064,   425331717,
       -1371911328,  1193314423,  -467566592, -2058209927,   717747104,
        -728216341, -2099700736,   899712045,  -318443040, -1457710305,
        1778384896,   801434401,   -92048864,  -900499949, -1622334464,
        2039018837,  1495248992,  1042966727,   683835392,   419538377,
         251779232,   182281787,   212790272,   345069437,   580904672,
         922102127,  1370488832,  1927912817, -1698724064,  -917596829,
         -21761024,   990716581,  2121790816,  -921529065,   452689920,
        1951500825,  -718021216,  1036123019, -1373914112,   643911373,
       -1498203168,   791831487, -1073741824,  1497211841,   -83018720,
       -1517219661,  1491846144,   356537333,  -625862048, -1453011609,
       -2122547200], dtype=int32)
```

where you can see there are negative numbers, which is because `int32` isn't a big enough type to handle the fifth power of all your numbers:

```
In [4]: np.iinfo(np.int32)
Out[4]: iinfo(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, dtype=int32)
```

but

```
In [104]: np.iinfo(np.int64)
Out[104]: iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)
```

which is sufficient.

So, if I switch to

```
b = np.arange(20,201, dtype=np.int64)
```

and

```
np.array(lambdas, dtype=np.int64)
```

then I get

```
(27, 84, 110, 133)
```

as expected.

(Optimization point #1: if you use `itertools.combinations`, not only won't you have to nest your loops but you will be much faster because you won't look for every permutation of the numbers.

Optimization point #2: `in a` can be very slow when `a` is an array because it has to scan the entire list.  If you make `a` a set, membership testing will be almost instantaneous.)